# rxjs6 Timer not being triggered in Angular 6 subscription to observable timer placed in service

Tags: timer, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I'm trying to put a timer from rxjs 6 in an angular 6 service. And it's  not being triggered. I looked in the documentation without any luck. This is my service code(only the relevant part:

```
import { map,flatMap, catchError, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BehaviorSubject, of, throwError,timer, Observable } from "rxjs";

.....

  countdownTimer = new Observable<number>();


  formatCountdownTime(count) {
    const seconds = count % 60 < 10 ? '0' + Math.floor(count % 60) : Math.floor(count % 60);
    /*    if(count <= 1000){
         //set timer to NOT RUNNING state so it updates UI components like the button that depends on the count
          this.contributorManagerService.countdownTimerIsRunning.next(false);
       } */
       return Math.floor(count / 60) + ':' + seconds;
  }

  createCountdownTimerObservable(count){
    this.countdownTimer =  timer(0, 1000);

  }
```

and this is the consumption of the timer. I need to know when time has elapsed and that's why I'm passing that 3rd function parameter to the subscription since I need to enable a button when the time is up.

```
import { map,take } from 'rxjs/operators';


export class CampaignDataComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

 countdownTimerIsRunning = false ;
 count: number;


ngOnInit(){

/* I subscribe to the timer and the 3rd parameter indicates what to do when time has elapsed */
      this.sharedHelpersService.countdownTimer.
      pipe(
        take(this.count),
        map(() => {
          --this.count;

          return this.count;
        })
      ).subscribe(count=>{
        console.log("New count",count);

          if(count>0){
             this.countdownTimerIsRunning = true;
          }
      },
      err=>{
        console.log("Countdown timer error", err);
      },
      ()=>{
        console.log("Time has elapsed");
        this.countdownTimerIsRunning = false;
      });

}

}
```

Do you know why is not being triggered? It used to work when I used the whole chain on the component but since I need to consume it from other components I had to put it in a service and that broke it. Any ideas?. Thank you very much in advance

EDIT: Just to clarify, they all the components should consume the same countdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick to have a timer shared by multiple components:

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { timer, Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class CountdownService {

  private _countdown = new Subject<number>();

  countdown(): Observable<number> {
    return this._countdown.asObservable();
  }

  private isCounting = false;

  start(count: number): void {
    // Ensure that only one timer is in progress at any given time.
    if (!this.isCounting) {
      this.isCounting = true;
      timer(0, 1000).pipe(
        takeWhile(t => t < count),
        map(t => count - t)
      ).subscribe(
        t => this._countdown.next(t),
        null,
        () => {
          this._countdown.complete();
          this.isCounting = false;
          // Reset the countdown Subject so that a 
          // countdown can be performed more than once.
          this._countdown = new Subject<number>();
        }
        );
    }
  }
}
```

A component can initiate a countdown with

```
countdownService.start(myCountdownTime)
```

and all components interested in the countdown time can subscribe with

```
countdownService.countdown().subscribe(t => ...)
```

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sexrqx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: All the answers were really useful and Brandt thought me a lot about rxjs. For this particular case I had the need to create a service like yours for a couple of reasons and that's why I'm picking this answer

Comment: just to clarify, I had to create an additional behavior subject to check if a new timer has started since otherwise some components wouldn't update unless I refreshed the page, I added that over your solution and it worked really well

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this code

```
  pipe(
    take(this.count),
    map(() => {
      --this.count;

      return this.count;
    })
```

I am assuming there is no other code in the component than that so this.count initializes to 0.  You then subscribe to the observable and say effectively take(0), so then the observable immediately completes.

Comment: An ngIf condition made the component unreacheable. this helped me detect the first stage of the problem!!

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you need to consume the countdown from other components, if with that you mean that you need to consume the functionality from other components but that each component that subscribes has their own independent countdown, then you can do the following:

Service:

```
import { timer, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, takeWhile, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// startTime is in seconds
count(startTime: number): Observable<number> {
  return timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    takeWhile(t => t < startTime),
    map(t => startTime - t)
  )
}
```

Component:

```
// Count down for 10 seconds.
countdownService.count(10).subscribe(
  t => console.log(t), 
  null, 
  () => console.log('Done!')
)
```

This will print: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 Done!

Comment: First of all thanks for your help! No, all the components needs to consume the same countdown since it's to enable different UI components and the same countdown lives after components are destroyed and created

Comment: Sam Herrmann since one of the components initiates the countdown and then the same countdown is consumed by 2 components more that has UI elements that need to be updated

Comment: See my other answer. I hope that's more inline with your requirements.